# Extra Lines appearing while loading an xml in ie 11

Tags: javascript

Recently I was facing an issue while loading an xml in IE11.So I went through different links and solved the issue and now the xml is getting loaded but multiple blank rows are appearing.
I do not have any clue how this issue can be solved.
I am providing below the code which I am using to load the xml in IE11 and also the screenshot with multiple blank rows:

Code:

```
function loadXMLDoc(fname)
{
var xmlDoc;
var nVer = navigator.appVersion;
var nAgt = navigator.userAgent;
var nameOffset, verOffset, ix;
// code for IE
if (window.ActiveXObject!=="undefined")
{
xmlDoc = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
} 


if ((verOffset = nAgt.indexOf("Chrome")) == -1 || (verOffset = nAgt.indexOf("Safari")) == -1)
{
    xmlDoc.async = false;
    xmlDoc.load(fname);
    return(xmlDoc);
}
}
function displayResult(xmlData)
{
xml = loadXMLDoc(xmlData);
xsl = loadXMLDoc("finalsheet.xsl");
// code for IE
if (window.ActiveXObject!=="undefined")
{
    ex = xml.transformNode(xsl);
    return ex;
}
```

Here is a screenshot of the issue, XML is getting displayed with multiple blank rows above and below the data

[image]

Comment: Your screenshot is not working; please fix it

Comment: Yes I have fixed it.Please click on the link for the screenshot.I am providing the link here as well.Link:http://i.stack.imgur.com/HD9X1.jpg